# Why the error is coming $this is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm having following code snippet:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.delete_question',function() { 
        var question_id = $this.closest('tr').attr('id');
        var $ele = $this.closest('tr').attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'match_question.php',
            data:{'request_type':'ajax', 'op':'delete','question_id':question_id},
            success: function(data) {
                 if(data=="YES") {
                    $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                 }else{
                        alert("can't delete the row");
                 }
             }

            });
        });
});
```

For the above code I'm getting an error as "ReferenceError: $this is not defined" in a console. But if I print some alert message at the beginning of the function it prints it. Then why the error is coming? Can you help me in this regard please?

Comment: You've never defined `$this`, what do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.delete_question', function () {
        //the variable $this needs to be defined
        var $this = $(this);
        //also $ele need to refer to the tr element not the id
        var $ele = $this.closest('tr');
        var question_id = $ele.attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'match_question.php',
            data: {
                'request_type': 'ajax',
                    'op': 'delete',
                    'question_id': question_id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "YES") {
                    $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                } else {
                    alert("can't delete the row");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message is quite clear, your code is using the variable `$this` that however was not defined and such an operation is an error. May be there's some confusion about `$`, `this`, `$this` and `$(this)`...

### `this`

`this` is a reserved word in Javascript and has a special meaning and special properties. It's used to refer to the "current context" when executing a function and its value is the object when the code executed is from a method call.

For example if you have an object `obj` the two fragments

```
obj.foo();
```

and

```
m = obj.foo; m();
```

are not equivalent because when executing the code of `foo` in the first case `this` will be `obj` while in the second case `this` will be the global object.

### `$this`

`$this` instead for Javascript is just a variable like any other, there's nothing special about the char `$` for Javascript and it can be used freely for identifiers.

### `$`

Like said before the character `$` is not special and `$` is a valid identifier exactly like `a` or `Q`. JQuery happened to choose a single bare `$` as a (the) function name because it was short and it wasn't used often (so it was unlikely to collide with other variables).

### `$(this)`

Probably the snipped you took the code from was using `$(this)` (just guessing)... and it's something completely different from `$this` because `$(this)` is the return value of calling the JQuery function `$` passing the current value of `this`.

Answer (score 2):

Add brackets around `this`. Less code. :}

***Also note:*** both of those variables produce the exact same string. I'd remove one, making for even less code. ;)

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.delete_question',function() { 
        var question_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        var $ele = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

        ......
    )};
)};
```